# Searching for Singular and Plural of a word in Search Engine

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

anyone here that can help me with my problem on our "Search" function in our application wherein they like to have the same result for this two example word which is **Toy** and **Toys**.

So for example if they searched for "**Toy**" then the application should return all data that has "**Toy**" in it or "**Toys**" and vise versa for "**Toys**".

I already use **.Contains()** in LINQ since this is the best way to achieve this result but when I check for "**Toy**" it searched for "**Toy**" and "**Toys**" and then when I searched for "**Toys**" it only search for "**Toys**" and no "**Toy**"

Here is my sample code:

```
context.CapabilityHasMethodHasSubstances
    .Where(c => c.Substance.SubstanceLocale.Where(x => x.LocaleId == 2057).FirstOrDefault()
    .Description.Contains(filter) && !c.IsDeleted)
    .Select(c => c.CapabilityId).ToList()
```

Thanks in advance for someone who can help me with my problem. :)

Comment: Im guessing change tofrom .Contains(filter) to .(Contains(filter) || .Contains(filter"+s"))  and yes that would turn sheep to sheeps, but you should have no sheeps

Comment: ahmm but do you think there's a problem here when your search keyword actually has "s" at the end, like for example "news" then this will add another "s" base on the code? or are we going to remove the "s" at the end but the problem now will be the result since "news" is different from "new". Thanks again.

Comment: You can use a library like [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) to pluralize/singuralize

Comment: @g0y yes, but surely you could check it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea for this would be to introduce some collection of `alias` for your `filter`(search word).

Your task now is to resolve plural forms, which can achieved by this. Also if you have to assign synonyms to given words later, you can easily expand this.

```
    Dictionary<string, string> AliasDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
       {  "Toys" , "Toy"},     // plural form
       {  "Game" , "Toy"},     // synonym 
       {  "Games" , "Toy"},    // plural synonym
       { "Sheeps" , "Sheep" }
    };

    public string ResolveAlias(string alias)
    {
        if (AliasDict.ContainsKey(alias))
        {
            return AliasDict[alias];
        }
        return alias;
    }
```

In your code simply at the method like this:

```
context.CapabilityHasMethodHasSubstances
    .Where(c => c.Substance.SubstanceLocale.Where(x => x.LocaleId == 2057).FirstOrDefault()
    .Description.Contains(ResolveAlias(filter)) && !c.IsDeleted)
    .Select(c => c.CapabilityId).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi @Smartis. I will try this and I think this is a good solution for my problem. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Using [PluralizationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice(v=vs.110).aspx) could be another solution.

This class has methods like:

- [IsPlural](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.isplural(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IsSingular](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.issingular(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Pluralize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.pluralize(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Singularize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.singularize(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Fun with Noun Pluralization libraries and the .NET Framework](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FunWithNounPluralizationLibrariesAndTheNETFramework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Before query use this to check whether the string is singular or plural. than use .Contain() in linq.

```
filter = Regex.Replace(filter, "s$|es$", "");
```

Comment: Bad idea. There are non-plural words matching the regex.